# UWP: How to bind a Textblock to a .txt file?

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

The file "sample.txt" is in the Assets folder, and contains a single line with the text "hello, world".
I would like to bind its content to a Textblock control.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to the contents of the file:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += async (s, e) =>
        {
            const string Filename = @"Assets\sample.txt";
            var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(Filename);
            textBlock1.Text = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(file.Path);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Extract the text from the file using [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-6.0) and assign it to a property on a class that implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0). Bind this property to the `TextBlock`.Text property.

Your view model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Text
    {
        get => this.text;
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Text))
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Your view:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        
        this.Loaded += async (s, e) =>
        {
            var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\sample.txt");

            this.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel
            {
                Text = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(file.Path),
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Within your MainPage XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text}"
```

To detect changes in the txt-file, use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Hi, the code to read the .txt file I already had. So I did the next step you suggested: create a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
But I don't know how to assign the value obtained from the txt file to the property in the class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
I'm researching how to do this.

Comment: the code that reads the .txt file                                                          

private async void HDUsedSpace()
        {
            string fname = @"Assets\Space_C.txt";
            StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(fname);
            if (File.Exists(file.Path))
            {
                DriveC.Text = File.ReadAllText(fname);
            }            
        }

Comment: the class, I don't know if it is correct                             

public class HD_Space : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // These fields hold the values for the public properties.  
        private string HD_UsedSpaceValue = String.Empty;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.

Comment: private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        // The constructor is private to enforce the factory pattern.  
        private HD_Space()
        {
            HD_UsedSpaceValue = "Test";
        }

        // This is the public factory method.  
        public static HD_Space CreateNewHD_Space()
        {
            return new HD_Space();
        }

Comment: public string HD_UsedSpace
        {
            get
            {
                return this.HD_UsedSpaceValue;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this.HD_UsedSpaceValue)
                {
                    this.HD_UsedSpaceValue = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

Comment: Apologies for posting the code in separate parts

Comment: I have added some example code.